# K nearest neighbor with varying feature length

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-scaling, k-nn

I'm trying to build a tool which predicts the elemental composition of some light source using its emission spectrum with the k nearest neighbor algorithm (I'm using the KNeighborsClassifier from scikit-learn in python). Therefor I have gathered the data of some emissions spectra of individual elements:

[image: Data of emission spectra]

Then I have added Gaussian noise to the individual spectra to create synthetic data for the training process. To get the same feature length for the training data and the unknown spectrum, I take the longest training data (in my case: Neon) and fill the unknown spectrum and the training data of the other elements with 0.0 until they have the same length. To make a prediction on the unknown spectrum, I'm creating every unique combination of it, e.g.:

unknown_spectrum = [1,2,3]
-> every combination = [[1,0,0], [0,2,0], [0,0,3], [1,2,0], [1,0,3], [0,2,3], [1,2,3]]

I'm doing this because the spectral lines of some element can be in between the spectral lines of another element. By doing this, I'm basically trying to "unmix mixed colors". This is where the first problem arises: the number of combinations is given by

$combination = 2^{length(unknownspectrum)} - 1$

which for a spectrum with 64 spectral lines would be 1.8446744e+19 combinations.

Now let's come to the second problem: Let's consider an unknown spectrum:

unkown_spectrum = [383.5384, 434.0462, 486.1279, 656.2852] (which is the spectrum for hydrogen, except some emission lines are missing).

When using my trained model on this spectrum, the prediction would be Beryllium. Which makes sense when comparing it to the data.

My questions are:

How could I be able to implement the "unmixing" of the spectrum without creating every possibility, which would take ages to do? Is it even necessary to do, or can the prediction be done without it?

Is it possible to train the knn model with different feature lengths instead of artificially lengthening them with 0.0?

How would I prevent false predictions because of the feature length, like in the given example?

Comment: This seems to be a classical problem. Maybe this survey would be useful to you [Duarte, Moussaoui, Jutten, Source Separation in Chemical Analysis (2014)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6784054).